# Wordpress and Woocommerce Chinese Permalink

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

So I've been working on this ecommerce site but I've problem with chinese character permalink.

For example `localhost/product-category/红蜻蜓` will render 404, as it will completely substitute the chinese character to question mark, like so `localhost/product-category/?/` . Same goes to `/localhost/archives/category/...`

I'm looking for a way to make it work, but not by translating it to pinyin or english/latin.

Any .htaccess/web.config(It's running under IIS) approach or it's technically not possible? Or do I need plugins like WPML (it's english website but having products with chinese character). Couldn't find any working solution, just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by IIS. If you already have `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />` in your web.config, that should be enough with this addition to your `index.php` in the Wordpress root installation directory

`if (isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];
}`

The php code is quite self explanatory.